# Receptor-ligand database

Tags: database, public-databases, protein-protein-interaction

How can I find ligands of receptors (or *vice versa*)?

For example, I want to find the receptors of IL-8 (CXCL8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CellPhoneDB](https://www.cellphonedb.org) is a publicly available repository of *curated* receptors, ligands and their interactions.

The interactions can be searched or downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [STRING](https://string-db.org/cgi/input.pl?sessionId=QLEnNyQMCbBE&input_page_show_search=on)?

It's a publicly available protein-protein interaction database, so it won't be a complete picture.

[Ingenuity Pathways Analysis (IPA)](https://www.qiagenbioinformatics.com/products/ingenuity-pathway-analysis/) is really nice but is a paid service. Ask your institution if they have a license for one.

Comment: Can you include a link to IPA please.

Comment: https://www.qiagenbioinformatics.com/products/ingenuity-pathway-analysis/

Answer (score 0):

[CellTalkDB](http://tcm.zju.edu.cn/celltalkdb/search.php) is another option for a searchable ligand-receptor database. According to the webpage it is curated from other databases and the literature. Details are available in the [publication](https://academic.oup.com/bib/advance-article-abstract/doi/10.1093/bib/bbaa269/5955941).